# Show control on top in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

If you have a button that i want to show on top? how do i do this, its now under a Picture box.

Comment: This needs to be much clearer in what is being asked

Comment: One point for completely misleading title of the year award though!

Comment: @Joe: Now we just need "community badges", where the community can vote to give someone a special badge... :D

Comment: @Dean - there's no need of adding such tags, it is discouraged. Soon enough(?) you'll be able to vote. Have fun.

Comment: well som did get it, and i even got a anwser to my question, so it coldent have been that misleading.

Comment: @Darkmage - don't take it seriously I was only having a bit of fun. Your original title, "C# designer Qestion, how to move controllers in layers?" suggested a question to do with object-oriented design, layered architecture etc such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_(object-oriented_design) . The words "controller", "layer", "design" all have more than one meaning...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click the button directly in design surface and choose "Bring to front". If you are having problems locating the control in the designer, use "Document outline" pane, select the button there and drag it higher up in the tree.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Document outline pane, the single most valuable tool when something in your Windows Forms Designer goes horribly wrong ;)

Comment: yes, the Document Outline is one of the best tools for designing a form and it leads just a shadowy existence.